# Tracking down youtube videos that are not available on mobile devices

Tags: youtube-api

I'm playing youtube videos on my mobile app using an embeded url.
The problem is that some videos "contain content from WMG" and are not availalble
(i.e https://www.youtube.com/embed/XeTwPGOjNzc?rel=0&showinfo=0)

Is there anyway I can track which videos are not restricted?

Thanks

Comment: the video you present in example is embedable http://jsbin.com/nihizugehe/1/ or maybe it's only on mobile devices ?

Comment: The video is not available when trying to be played from a mobile device